# Using @ at the beginning of table names in Oracle/SqlServer/PgSql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, postgresql, special-characters

I'm trying to understand if there is any cons in using table names that starts with the `@` sign.

We need a well-identifiable pattern to distinguish these tables from other in the same schema.

We currently work with all the followings:
 - Oracle 10g and up
 - SqlServer 2008 R2 and up
 - Postgres 9.1 and up

I tried with all of them and the table creation succeed, but I can't find good documentation to find out if this is actually permitted.

Comment: The naming requirements for objects in all of those environments are well documented. Just don't break the naming requirements.

Comment: @SeanLange No, temporary tables starts with `#`.

Comment: @DavidAldridge As I wrote in the edit I can't find good docs especially for Oracle and Pg.

Comment: It's actually table variables that start with @ in SQL Server

Comment: `@` is illegal in a SQL identifier.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=oracle+rdbms+object+naming&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wbgaVdP9GOmq8we43YCYBQ

Comment: In SQL Server you can filter on part of a name if you cannot use the preferred method of schema. You can start every object name with a dept name (such as payroll_) and set up a filter in SQL Server Management Studio that will only display names that contain a particular string.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits thanks, but we need a DB-indipendent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is an illegal character for an identifier in (standard) SQL.

The rules for valid (legal) identifiers that do not need double quotes are documented in the manuals:

The [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) essentially quotes the SQL standard:

> *SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($)*

The [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) essentially says the same:

> *Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#).*

Note that Oracle has one exception when it comes to DBLinks:

> *Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.*

You *can* include a `@` in an identifier if you use quoted identifiers. But the Oracle manual also states: *Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names*

Comment: I've no particular problems with non-quoted identifiers, since our abstraction layer always adds double quotes. Anyway, it's seems to be a bit risky to use these special chars (assuming I don't want to use `_`).

Comment: @Teejay: but beware that quoted identifiers are case **sensitive**. `"FooBar"` is a different name than `"FOOBAR"` (not necessarily in SQL Server though)

Comment: Yes, we are aware of that. All our tables are uppercase.

Comment: Assuming I don't want to use `_` we will probably end up using `_` :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Using @ at the beginning of table names in Oracle

I would stick to Oracle in my answer.

AFAIK, Oracle won't allow you to do so.

Even if it is allowed. Practically, one such place where it would be an issue is `SQL*Plus`. It would be a disaster to execute scripts if you have the **"at"(@) sign** in the **begining** of the **table_name**.

The only exception I know, quoting from the Oracle documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm:

> Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start each name for a group with a common string such as acctg or payroll and search the name through the information_schema.table view which is supposed to be in 'every' database.  To sell a list of all tables that start with acctg you will have to do a:

select * from information_schema.tables where left(name,5)='acctg' should work on all the products you listed.